# can't choose seek time of a video from a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, mongodb, video, html5-video

I want to use a video tag and control it with javascript,
but it doesn't work as I want.

```js
function vidplay(evt) {
  if (video.src == "") { // inital source load
    getVideo();
  }
  button = evt.target; //  get the button id to swap the text based on the state
  if (video.paused) { // play the file, and display pause symbol
    video.play();
    button.textContent = "||";
  } else { // pause the file, and display play symbol
    video.pause();
    button.textContent = ">";
  }
}
//  load video file from input field
function getVideo() {
  var d = document.getElementById('a4').innerHTML; // video file name

  // var fileURL = document.getElementById("videoFile").value;  // get input field
  var fileURL = d; // get input field
  if (fileURL != "") {
    video.src = fileURL;
    video.load(); // if HTML source element is used
    document.getElementById("play").click(); // start play
  } else {
    errMessage("Enter a valid video URL"); // fail silently
  }
}
```

`var d` in function `getVideo()` is like `"http://192.168.44.112/~/~.mp4"`

This video was uploaded on mongoDB and I want to use it.

The video works well but the seek bar doesn't work at all,
it only seeks to time `0`.

```js
document.getElementById("rew").addEventListener("click", function() {
  setTime(-10);
}, false);

document.getElementById("fwd").addEventListener("click", function() {
  setTime(10);
}, false);


function setTime(tValue) {
  //  if no video is loaded, this throws an exception
  try {
    if (tValue == 0) {
      video.currentTime = tValue;
    } else {
      video.currentTime += tValue;
    }

  } catch (err) {
    // errMessage(err) // show exception
    errMessage("Video content might not be loaded");
  }
}
```

And when i use `setTime()` function, it goes to seek time `0`, while I want to seek at the time corresponding to where I click .

How can I do it ?

Comment: Can't really repro:https://jsfiddle.net/05tchy8v/ Also, you talked about scroll bars, but here we only can guess there are 3 buttons, nothing in your code let us think anything about a "scroll bar".

Answer (score 0):

I made this quick example that you can test & study, then afterwards you can just apply a similar logic to your above shown code. Hope it helps your problem.

```
<video id="myVid" width="640" height="480" controls>
     <source src="yourVideoFile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


<script>

tValue = 0; //start at zero

myVid.addEventListener('seeking', function(e){ tValue = myVid.currentTime })

function setTime_FWD() 
{
    try 
    {
        if (tValue >= myVid.duration) { tValue = myVid.duration; }
        else { tValue += 10; myVid.currentTime = tValue; }
    } 
    catch (err) { errMessage("Video content might not be loaded"); }    
}

function setTime_RWD() 
{
    try 
    {
        tValue -= 10;
        if (tValue <= 0) { myVid.currentTime = tValue = 0; }
        else { myVid.currentTime = tValue; }
    }
    catch (err) { errMessage("Video content might not be loaded"); }
}


</script>


<br><br>

<button onclick="setTime_RWD()"> << </button>

<button onclick="setTime_FWD()"> >> </button>
```

Comment: myVid.totalTime? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the heads-up. Should be `myVid.duration`. I've fixed it. PS: Don't ask where comes from (it's a long story)...

Comment: You can use ternary operators.  setTime_RWD()  could be condensed into

    myVid.currentTime = myVid.currentTime > 10 ? myVid.currentTime - 10 : 0;

Comment: @BenjaminBelisle that's a good suggestion. I hope Asker tries it out when they modify their own `function setTime()`.

Comment: @VC.One Sorry for late answer. It's not work for me. I think because this video is from mongoDB. And streaming video.

Comment: Can you provide a temporary testable link (can delete later)? Also are you saying it is a **live** stream?